# Excluding a single element in XSLT when using document()

Tags: xslt, nodes, dita

I'm using document() to copy the content of an XML file (tagged for DITA) into a variable. Here is the code I had used previously that worked:

```
<xsl:variable name="fileContent">
    <xsl:copy-of select="document($fileSrc)"/>
</xsl:variable>
```

Now, I want to include everything except the `<draft-comment>` element. I've tried to change document() as follows:

```
<xsl:variable name="fileContent">
    <xsl:copy-of select="document($fileSrc)/*[not(draft-comment)]"/>
</xsl:variable>
```

This doesn't seem to work. The  text is still there. Any suggestions on how I can fix this? Thank you for your help.

Comment: Seeing an example of the `$fileSrc` document would be helpful.

Answer (score 4):

Create two templates with the `mode` attribute; one to copy nodes unchanged, and one to ignore `draft-comment`

```
<xsl:template match="@*|node()" mode="document">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()" mode="document" />
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="draft-comment" mode="document" />
```

Then you can use `xsl:apply-templates` instead of `xsl:copy-of`

```
<xsl:variable name="fileContent">
   <xsl:apply-templates select="document($fileSrc)" mode="document" />
</xsl:variable>
```

Note that `xsl:copy-of` does a deep-copy, and your existing statement will copy the root element and everything under it just as long as it doesn't have a child node called `draft-comment`